# How do you make pylint in VSCode know that it's in a package (so that relative imports work)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import, pylint

Layout:

```
workspace/
  .vscode/launch.json
  main.py
  foo.py:
    def harr(): pass
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/..",
            "module": "${workspaceFolderBasename}"
        }
    ]
}
```

main.py and pylint error:

```
from .foo import harr
   ^

Attempted relative import beyond top-level package - pylint(relative-beyond-top-level)
```

The program runs fine if not for the linter error. I have tried modifying sys.path in __init__.py and through pylintrc but the result is the same.

Is there a way VSCode can run linting for a file and know at the same time that the file is part of a package?

I've scanned through [vscode linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) and the pylint config docs but found nothing like what I'd expect. This should be so standard, what am I not getting? How is pylint supposed to work out relative imports if it has no idea of the top-level package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently pylint cannot find modules accurately through relative imports, it will mess up the path, although the code can run.

You could try the following two ways to solve it:

1.Add the following settings in the setting.json file.

> ```
> "python.linting.pylintArgs": 
>   ["--disable=all", 
>     "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode",
>     "--disable=E0402", 
>   ],
> ```

(Since there is no issue with the code, we can turn off this type of pylint prompt.)

2. Since the relative import method will make pylint confusing, we can avoid such use.

   Use '`from foo import harr`' instead of '`from .foo import harr`'.

Reference: [Default Pylint rules](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but rather suboptimal solutions. Quite sad of pylint. I suppose if python import system wouldn't be such a wreck, they would have no problem supporting this.

Answer (score 5):

I suffered from the same issue earlier this morning.

It turns out than you can just add init .py file in your root path.

```
workspace/
    .vscode/launch.json
    __init__.py
    main.py
    foo.py
```

Comment: One other thing to note: your Python package must be sitting in a folder that has been added to your VS Code workspace. If you have `__init__.py` files in your Python package but still get the `pylint-relative-beyond-top-level` error, please add your project's top-level folder to your workspace.